# Lambert W function largest solution

Tags: lambert-w

I'm trying to understand a demonstration on a paper and since my math knowledge is limited i can't understand how do i deduce the value of $\,\gamma$ given a value for $k$ and $n$.

The equation is the following: $\gamma = n\frac{k+\textit{W}(-ke^{-k})}{k}$, where $\textit{W}(x)$ is the largest solution of $x = We^W$

Lets say for instance that k = 2, what would be the value of $W(-2e^{-2})$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\require{begingroup} \begingroup$
$\def\e{\mathrm{e}}\def\W{\operatorname{W}}\def\Wp{\operatorname{W_0}}\def\Wm{\operatorname{W_{-1}}}\def\Catalan{\mathsf{Catalan}}$

For any $k>0$ there are two real values,
$\Wp(-k\e^{-k})$ and $\Wm(-k\e^{-k})$,
where $\Wp$ is the principal branch
and $\Wm$ is the other real branch
of the Lambert $\W$ function,
and the following relation holds:

\begin{align}
\Wm(-k\e^{-k})&\le -1
\le \Wp(-k\e^{-k}) <0
.
\end{align}

As for this specific value, for $k=2$,
\begin{align}
\Wm(-2\e^{-2})&=-2
,\\
\Wp(-2\e^{-2})&=-2\,\varrho
\approx -0.40637574
,
\end{align}
where $\varrho\approx 0.20318787\ $ is so-called [the rumor constant](http://oeis.org/A106533).

The maximum of the two values for $k>0$ is always $\Wp(-k\e^{-k})$,
and for $k\in(0,1)$ it is simple, $\Wp(-k\e^{-k})=-k$,
but for $k>1$ we must have $\Wm(-k\e^{-k})=-k<-1$,
so the maximum
is still $\Wp(-k\e^{-k})\in(-1,0)$.

$\endgroup$

Comment: Hope i can now solve this problem. Thank you!

Comment: @dinoroba: If the answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.